# If I have a web server with 10 process and 10 threads, what does that mean?

Tags: python, ajax, multithreading, process

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Spawning/

So I'm playing with Spawning...
If I run it with 10 process and 10 threads, what does that mean?

I'm building a chat room (long-polling using eventlet).  Does that mean that only 10 people can be present in the chat room?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It all depends on the architecture of your application. Event-based apps can support large amounts of connections (users, sessions, whatever matters in your app) *in a single thread*.

You usually need multiple threads when you're performing blocking IO operations, and multiple processes when you need true computational load distribution. In something simple like a chat application, you can easily avoid the need for both. The standard Python library has the `asyncore` and `asynchat` modules which you may find interesting. The Twisted library is a more comprehensive approach.

Answer (score 0):

No. Having a certain number of threads/processes doesn't create or change any kind of limit on the content or clients. Having more threads/processes can improve the performance of an application when balanced across them, especially on SMP systems where a single-thread or single-process architecture would be limited to one CPU.